# One-liner for sorting a dict by values and then by keys?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Suppose I have the following dict...

```
sample = {
  'a' : 100,
  'b' : 3,
  'e' : 42,
  'c' : 250,
  'f' : 42,
  'd' : 42,
}
```

I want to sort this dict with the highest order sort being by value and the lower order sort being by key.

The key-value pairs of the result would be this ...

```
( ('b', 3), ('d', 42), ('e', 42), ('f', 42), ('a', 100), ('c', 250) )
```

I already know how to do this by writing several lines of python code. However, I'm looking for a python one-liner that will perform this sort, possibly using a comprehension or one or more of python's functional programming constructs.

Is such a one-liner even possible in python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a lambda that uses both the value and key.

```
sorted(sample.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
```

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot about the `key` argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the operator module:

```
import operator
sample = {
 'a' : 100,
 'b' : 3,
 'e' : 42,
 'c' : 250,
 'f' : 42,
 'd' : 42,
}

sorted_by_value = tuple(sorted(sample.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))

sorted_by_key = tuple(sorted(sample.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0)))
```

sorted_by_value:

```
(('b', 3), ('e', 42), ('d', 42), ('f', 42), ('a', 100), ('c', 250))
```

sorted_by_key:

```
 (('a', 100), ('b', 3), ('c', 250), ('d', 42), ('e', 42), ('f', 42))
```

Comment: Your answer only shows sorting by the keys of the dictionary.

Comment: The sorted_by_value variable sorts the dictionary by value, while the sorted_by_key variable sorts the dictionary by key. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: Yes, but neither returns the list that I specified in my original question.

Comment: Please see my recent edit. The code now returns a tuple of sorted items, not a list.